# Npm doesn't run any scripts from package.json

Tags: javascript, shell, npm

When I try to run any package.json script from any working project nothing happens. Here is an example console log.

[image: nothing happens!!!]

My package.json:

[image]

Comment: what do you have in these scripts?

Comment: Share your package.json and scripts content

Comment: As I mentioned before, npm doesn't run scripts in any working project. That's why this is a problem with npm

Comment: Which `Node.js` version are you using?

Comment: node version 12.13.1

Comment: does it work with yarn like "yarn start" ??? Coz from npm you will need 'npm run-script run'